# RVM install ruby into a different directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am trying to install several versions of ruby using rvm (multiuser install) and want to have the different ruby versions in specific folders, for ex. /opt/ruby-1.9.2, /opt/ruby-2.0.0, /opt/ruby-2.1.10
Is there a install configuration argument that would let me install to a specific directory ?
Would I run something like:
     rvm install 2.1.1 -C --enabled-shared,--prefix=/opt/ruby2.1.1
?

Comment: So I tried:  /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm install 2.0.0 -C --enabled-shared,--prefix=/opt/ruby2.0.0   and it failed. Looks like the defaults are --enabled-shared   and --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/src/{version}  and /usr/local/rvm/rubies/{version}  even with the --prefix